# Conversation Lists in Android

Tags: java, android, sms

I am a complete newbie when it comes to Android and have never touched a piece of Android code in my life. I am trying to build an SMS application in Android for my Software Engineering project this semester (yes, the professor has required to build this SMS app). He has only given us 2 weeks to do this project and he is expecting a full software development process, github documentation, collaboration by the team from everybody, and the list goes on.

My specific task in the team is to implement a conversation list similar to any stock default SMS messaging application. Could anyone provide a step by step guide on how to build a conversation list such as the one in the stock SMS application? By that I mean showing me which parts to implement, when and where. Not necessarily any specific code unless it is going to be something that I am probably not going to be able to figure out in 2 weeks.

I kindly am asking you experts here to please help me out and point me in the right direction of things that I need to implement since time is so so short. It would be so much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you "have never touched a piece of Android code in [your] life", we have no basis for being able to explain "what parts to implement, when and where" using any terminology that you will understand. Personally, I would not consider your project suitable for anything less than somebody on their second semester of Android app development (not some general software engineering course). That being said, [this library](https://github.com/himanshu-soni/ChatMessageView) may give you a leg up on the conversation UI.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and library link. I know that it may be really hard for you guys to try to explain something to someone who does not know the terminology. I have no idea why my professor has given us this task. The whole class is in a frantic panic.

Comment: @commonsWare Would you happen to know where I could find something similar for the conversation list that shows up when you first open the stock SMS app? You know, how the different message threads are shown for each contact you are talking to?

Comment: Please bear in mind that there are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of "stock SMS app" implementations, spread over the thousands of Android device models. Use screenshots (uploaded somewhere and linked to from your question) rather than references to apps that we might not share. Using the "stock SMS app" on my Nexus 4, the conversation list would just be a `ListView` (or a `RecyclerView`), with `TextView` and `ImageView` widgets in each row for each conversation.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you! That is actually about to help me a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two weeks is not a lot of time so I'm going to assume the scope will be somewhat limited to:

- Show a list of conversations
- Show a list of messages per conversation
- Be able to send and receive messages

I'm also assuming you don't have to handle MMS and can just stick to SMS.

Fortunately Google has released two messaging apps as open source - the old "Mms" app and the new "Messaging" app:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Mms/
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Messaging/

Digging into these code bases can be a bit daunting, especially the new Messaging app, but the legacy Mms app gives you many of the building blocks.

In a nutshell you'll need to:

- Set up permissions and create a BroadcastReceiver to handle the SMS deliver intent (incoming SMS). A tip is to read a bit about what it means to be a "Default SMS app" in Android here: http://android-developers.blogspot.se/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html
- Read the SmsMessage object from the intent. Pick out the parts and store these values to the SmsProvider (see the public API in Telephony.java). You might need to create a message thread (conversation) if it doesn't already exist.
- Build an activity with a listview and a cursor adapter to load conversations (threads) from the SmsProvider.
- In the adapter, process the cursor data and create views that represent conversation data, such as recipient, timestamp and snippet. These will then be displayed in the listview.
- Create another activity (or fragment) with a listview and a cursor adapter to load messages from the SmsProvider. Possibly use a CursorLoader though it can take time to figure out how to set these up.
- As in the previous adapter, process the cursor data and produce views that represent messages.
- Inside the activity/fragment that shows messages for a conversation, create an EditText where the user can type the message, and a button to process the send command. SmsManager.java is the public API used for sending text messages. If the adapter is set up correctly (this is very convenient with the CursorLoader, but you can do manual queries to the provider as well), it'll get notified and create the new view for the new message.

Comment: Oh wow, well this answer is much more specific! Great thank you. And yes, you are spot on with the requirements!

Comment: in your second bullet point, are you talking about programming threads or "message" threads? I know in your third bullet point, you are talking about messaging threads. Sorry for the confusion. lol. I just want to be entirely sure I am getting this right

Comment: @JamesCombs Sorry, I meant message thread (or "conversation"). I'll update the answer! It raises an important point though.. access to the provider is limited to a single thread at a time, and it's good practice in Android to do slow running operations (such as reading from a DB) in a background thread. CursorLoader does this automatically for you, but keep in mind that these can be hard to set up if you're new to Android. Given the limited time though I'd just do everything on the main thread and make a note of which operations should be offloaded to background threads (or AsyncTasks).

Comment: exactly! thanks a lot for the guidance. I have already made lots of significant progress. My app is now the default messaging application. I am able to send/receive SMS messages in my messaging activity and I have a conversation ListView set up as my main activity. Clicking is registered to the list items and takes me to my messaging activity. All I have to do is implement the individual message threads and pull the right information I want to store and display in the ListView list items once I decide on how I am going to set up the SMSObject!! All in a few hours with your help!

Comment: All I have to do is spend this weekend working with the CursorLoader and figuring out how I am going to implement the rest of your bullet points. Luckily I am a fast learner, Just felt pretty upset that the professor gave us something we have never seen and only 2 weeks to do it. :(

Comment: Great to hear, keep it up! :) And yes, two weeks to write a fully functioning SMS app on a new platform is not much.

Comment: Im having trouble finding good information on how to go about creating the message thread objects and populating the list with them. Would you happen to be able to point me to a post or guide?

Comment: You can create the message thread by using this API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Threads.html#getOrCreateThreadId(android.content.Context, java.lang.String). You'll also find many of the telephony URIs there. Basically you get a ContentResolver, create ContentValues with the values from the SmsMessage object, get the URI (from one of the classes in the android.provider.telephony package) and call the method on the resolver. Tip, see: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/master/src/java/android/provider/Telephony.java#406

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of tasks broken down that you would need to know in order to do this :

//Showing the list of messages
 1. What is an object
 2. How to populate a list of said objects
 3. How to display a list in a ListView in Android

//Sending a message
 1. How to add a new screen with a TextView/EditText and a Button
 2. How to bind the Button to an Intent
(Not sure if you are required to do the server code to send the message - that is too much for a two week project)

//Receiving messages
//Again - server code

Each of these samples and tutorials can be found with a simple Google search

Comment: Thank you for the quick breakdown. I will keep all of this in mind. This is what I am looking for, a list of things that I can go learn how to do quickly instead of being scattered around trying to figure something out.

Comment: No problem and goodluck. Generally this site is for more technically specific questions so once you have a few feel free to post them up and we will try to help.

PS can you mark this answer as the accepted answer